# Silverlight client-side database with LINQ

Tags: database, silverlight, silverlight-oob

I'm creating an out of browser silverlight app and would like to have a database in the client side. I've looked at sqlite but it seems that it does not work with silverlight.

It would be great if I could use LINQ with it. I would prefer a free solution but payed is always an option.

Any suggestion?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are some options:

http://silverdb.codeplex.com/
http://siaqodb.com/
http://www.mcobject.com/silverlight-demo
http://www.effiproz.com/product_sl.aspx

Comment: Thank you Klinger. Do you have experience with any of them?