# Silverlight out-of-browser + WCF RIA Services + Cassini + SQL Express as a desktop app

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I'm planning to develop a small business app that I'd like to be deployable either as a standalone desktop app or a web app.

I would like to know if having a Silverlight + WCF RIA Services stack will be challenging to deploy as a standalone desktop app (with Cassini and SQL Express). I'd like to reuse as much of the project as possible, so if it is possible to do it this way, I don't need to create a separate WPF version (with direct database calls) for the standalone desktop users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible if you plan on distributing an installer to package and configure everything for you. The major challenge is with the installer, you will have to deploy and start cassini as a service. You are going to have to configure IIS + make sure its even installed. Setup the app that hosts your WCF, etc.

But other than that, if you get that done, your good to go with a silverlight desktop app.

Now my question. Why do all this? Why not use a silverlight IsolatedStorage database engine like one from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608481/silverlight-client-side-database-with-linq/3611867#3611867).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'd like to reuse as much codebase as the one that's running on the web connected remotely to a database. If it is too much of a hassle, I may just need to have two data providers, one using WCF RIA Services, and another using the isolated storage.